# How to use create method in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo

I want to create a new record in my module, but I can not get the create method to work properly.

In my module, I added a many2one field that takes the partner_id. It shows the field filled with the correct data, but when I click on save it does not save the field's value.
I'm trying to save product_id...

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name', _('New')) == _('New'):
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('vehicle.delivery.transfer')
    vals['partner_id'] = self.env['res.partner'].search(['partner_id','in',self.partner_id.id])
    return super(VehicleDelivery, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: Update your question with onchange readonly field

Comment: You can find an answer at https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/can-change-the-value-of-a-readonly-field-using-onchange-function-114512

Comment: @YHussein could you post the code that you using to select the partner? and what you are doing there is wron, when you use `@api.model`  `self` is an empty `recordset` is literally a dummy record that you can use as proxy.

Comment: Yes please add the definition of your field `partner_id` that should help alot to answer your question. In one comment of Odedra's answer you've written something about `readonly`, i bet the problem lies exactly there, but it's difficult to answer without knowing the code behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Two points should be consider.

1. Make sure `name` field has default value `New`
2. `vals['partner_id']` coding line is wrong.

In `res.partner` table, we don't have field `partner_id`. And we can get data from `vals` instead of `self`. Like `vals.get('field_name')`

Comment: so if I want to save the partner_id, I should change the (vals['partner_id']) to what exactly, if in res.partner the field is name ?

Comment: `partner_id` already save in `vals`. You can remove that line. Try it.

Comment: Make notice that the field partner_id is readonly, and is automatically selected based on another field. The problem is when I click on "save" , all data saves correctly except partner_id stayes empty.